# Faking window focus (sandbox?, App-V?)

Tags: c#, virtualization, sandbox

I'm trying to figure out how I'd be able to essentially trick a window into thinking it has focus. What I've found out through some searching, is that I'd need some sort of sandbox to accomplish this. An intermediate layer between the OS and the window.

I'd appreciate some assistance in pointing me in the right direction of how I'd be able to accomplish this through C# (with pinvoke, etc, if necessary). To essentially launch another executable from the C# program, and set it up in some fashion to be on a faux desktop, with constant window focus. But still be able to interact with the window as normal (like a window wrapper, if you will, that can lose focus all it wants, but the window contained within will never think it's out of focus).

I'm sure this is quite an undertaking (though, maybe it won't be, perhaps someone knows an elegant solution to this), but I know it's possible, as I've seen something similar done in a commercial product. (I'm trying to emulate one of the behaviors of this sandbox product).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try calling an activation event:

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code
}
```

Then out of any functions, declare an eventarg:

```
private EventArgs ev;
```

Finally, when you want to fake a focus, call the activated function:

```
Form1_Activated(this, ev);
```

Hope that help!

Comment: Sorry, but, this isn't really related to the sort of thing I was talking about. I was more along the lines of tricking a 3rd party application into believing it has focus (Like a game or some such).

Answer (score 0):

You could try injecting a WM_ACTIVATE message into the target windows message queue.  This may trick it into thinking it has focus, even when it does not.  It really depends on how the application is checking for focus.